# Перегрука операции ввода для класса полиномов с вещественными коэффициентами

Tags: c++, классы

Мне нужно создать класс полиномов с вещественными коэффициентами, перегрузить для него операцию ввода и вывода и опеределить операции умножения, сложения, вычитания и взятие производной. Как перегрузить операции сложения, умножения и т.д. я понял, а вот перегрузка операции ввода у меня не получилась. Почему программа не хочет ничего вводить, просто пропускает этот шаг до system("pause"). В чём может быть проблема? 
Upd.
Да, спасибо, теперь всё вводится. Но есть вторая проблема - почему операция вывода выводит только первый элемент?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
class Polynom
{
public:
    unsigned n; //степень полинома
    double *koef; //указатель на массив коэффициентов полинома koef[i] - коэффициент при i-й степени
    Polynom();
    Polynom(unsigned an);//конструктор с параметрами
    Polynom(const Polynom &); //копирования
    ~Polynom();//деструктор
    unsigned getn(); //функция получения степени полинома
    double getkoef(unsigned); //функция получения коэффициента при i-й степени
    Polynom operator + (const Polynom &);   //оператор сложения двух полиномов
    Polynom operator = (const Polynom &);   //оператор присваивания
    friend ostream &operator<< (ostream &s, const Polynom &c); // перегруженный оператор вывода
    friend istream &operator >> (istream &s, Polynom &c); // перегруженный оператор ввода
    double &operator()(int i)
    {
        return koef[i];
    }
};
Polynom::Polynom() 
{
    koef = NULL;
}

Polynom::~Polynom()
{
    delete[]koef;
}
Polynom::Polynom(unsigned an)
{
    int i;
    unsigned n = an;
    koef = new double[n + 1];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        koef[i] = 0;
    }
}
Polynom::Polynom(const Polynom &f)
{
    n = f.n;
    koef = new double[n + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        koef[i] = f.koef[i];
}
unsigned Polynom::getn() 
{
    return n;
}
double Polynom::getkoef(unsigned i) 
{
    if (i <= n)
        return koef[i];
    else
        return 0.0;
}
Polynom Polynom::operator+(const Polynom &t) //сделал по-другому, если не сработает попробовать другим способом
{
    int i;
    if (n >= t.n)
    {
        Polynom Z(n);
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            Z.koef[i] = koef[i] + t.koef[i];
        return Z;
    }
    else
    {               
        Polynom Z(t.n);
        for (i = 0; i <= t.n; i++)
            Z.koef[i] = t.koef[i] + koef[i];
        return Z;
    }

}
Polynom Polynom::operator = (const Polynom &t) 
{
    n = t.n;
    delete[] koef;
    koef = new double[n + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        koef[i] = t.koef[i];
    return *this;
}
istream &operator>>(istream &s, Polynom &c)// перегруженный оператор ввода
{
    delete[]c.koef;
    c.koef = new double[c.n + 1];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < c.n; i++)
    {
        s >> c.koef[i];
    }
    return s;
}
ostream &operator<< (ostream &s, const Polynom &c)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < c.n; i++)
    {
        s << c.koef[i];
    }
    return s;
}
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int n;
    cout << "Введите степень полинома (максимальная степень Х с не нулевым коэфициентом):" << '\n';
    cin >> n;
    Polynom A(n);
    cout << "Введите коэфициенты полинома:" << '\n';
    cin >> A;
    cout << A;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Polynom A(n, ); - а это что?

Comment: Это я неправильно скопировал код. Уже исправил.
Должно было быть Polynom A(n)

Comment: У вас в операторах, работающих с потоком, цикл идёт `i < n`, но в остальных местах - `i <= n`

Comment: Да, спасибо, теперь всё вводится. Но есть вторая проблема - почему операция вывода выводит только первый элемент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конструкторе `Polynom::Polynom(unsigned an)` поле класса `n` не инициализируется, вместо этого объявляется локальная переменная с тем же именем. Соответственно в перегруженном операторе ввода `c.n` содержит мусор и обращение к нему приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Кроме того, не следует использовать `unsigned` в качестве типа, используйте [библиотечные целочисленные типы фиксированной длины](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint). И не стоит выделять / удалть память самостоятельно, используйте умные указатели или вектор.

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ! Без вас бы не заметил эту глупую ошибку.

Comment: А конструктор копирования правильно написан?

Comment: @Kirill Последний элемент в массиве может быть потенциально неиницилизирован.